# Quadratic formula and factoring are leading to different answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

$$x^{ 2 }-2x-15=0$$

By factoring, I get:

$$(x-5)(x+3)$$

Which has the solutions:

$$x=5, x=-3$$

However when I use the quadratic formula (which is what the book saids to use), I get

$$\frac { 2 \pm \sqrt { 4-(4\cdot1\cdot(-15)) }  }{ -2 } =$$
$$\frac { 2\pm 8 }{ -2 } $$

Which I evaluate to be $$x=-5, x=3$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Denominator should be $2$, not $-2$

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, just fyi: \pm in math mode gives you a nice-looking $\pm$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ax^2+bx+c=0\implies x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$$\implies x^2-2x-15=0\implies x=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{(-2)^2-4\cdot1(-15)}}{2\cdot1}=\frac{2\pm8}2=5,-3$$

Comment: That was a typo. I mean to put $$(x-5) (x+3)$$

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, Edited

Comment: Now I see the mistake I made. I was thinking $$a*b$$ goes in the denominator for some odd reason. It's supposed to be $$2a$$. got it.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is that the denominator should be $2$, not $-2$

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic formula is
$$
x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$
The denominator should be $2$ because
\[ a=1 \]
\[ b=-2 \]
\[ c=-15 \]
So then
\[
x=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{4-4(-15)}}{2}= \frac{2\pm \sqrt{64}}{2}= \frac{2\pm 8}{2}=1\pm 4
\]
Thus
$$ x=5 $$
$$ x=-3 $$